# Cypress assert is element inside array

Tags: arrays, cypress, assert

Can someone please, assist in following:
Short explanation: opened one page, taken text element, then opened second page nd among 4 or 5 elements, need to assert that element from page one, is inside created array of those several elements. Wrote this code:

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
'assertForOpenedElementVisible',
 (list1, list2, notDisplayedElementMsg) => {
const textsArray = []
cy.get('body').then((body) => {
  if (body.find(list1).length > 0) {
    cy.get(list1).each(($el, index) => {
      const text1 = $el.text().replace(', ', '')

      cy.get(list1).eq(index).click()
      cy.wait(1000)

      cy.get(list2)
        .each(($el, index) => {
          const text = $el.text().replace(', ', '')
          textsArray.push(text)
          cy.log(textsArray)
          cy.log(text)
        })
        .then(() => {
          cy.wrap(expect(textsArray).to.include(text1))
        })
    })
  } else {
    cy.log(notDisplayedElementMsg)
  }
 })
 }
)
```

And when check Test runner - I got elements, but test fails:

[image]

How to correctly assert that? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do an assertion like:

```js
expect(text1).to.be.oneOf(textsArray)
```

OR, you can directly assert without using `each()` as well like:

```js
cy.get(list2).should(($list2) => {
  expect($list2.eq(3)).to.contain('49') //If you know the position
})

cy.get(list2)
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    expect(text).to.contain('49') //If you don't know the position
  })
```

Comment: Tried, but it fails again with error:

AssertionError
expected '49' to be one of [ Array(4) ]

Comment: change `const textsArray = []` to `var  textsArray = []`.

Comment: @aAlapan Das - unfortunatelly, same error with 'var' instead 'const'

Comment: I don't know why `textsArray.push(text)` is not working and also in the first itration why the array size is 4 as per logs? Can you post your html for list2, so that I can debug some more? Also you don't have to use `cy.wrap` you can directly write the expect statement

Comment: Array is size 4 because there are 4 elements shown on page and one of them is just the one I need to assert. Unfortunately, can not provide you html, sorry for that. With or without cy.wrap, only changes error thrown, but it does not work either way

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: I choose second solution and it works. Thank you very much